# how to reduce spacing in material-ui?

Tags: material-ui

i am building web app for desktops and i find material-ui wastes lot of space when displaying the components right out of the box.

AppBar is rendered with padding of 24. 
Passing the style to the appbar is only adding in addition to 24 instead of overriding.

Just compare the height of menubar of stackoverflow vs material-ui appbar
How to reduce AppBar height atleast 10px less?

Comment: what is the Material-ui component you are trying to use for the AppBar?

Answer (score 0):

You can override component style. You need to apply a className or a style like this :

```
<AppBar className={classes.appBar} />
```

With web inspector, you can find your css class. Something like `MuiAppBar-XXXXXX`

Hope this help!